# PyCharm incorrectly detects type errors on decorated function's arguments

Tags: python, pycharm, decorator, inspection

I use PyCharm COMMUNITY 2018.2.

I wrote a code as follow.

```
def increment(func):
    def wrapper(count):
        """
        :param int count:
        """
        count += 1
        func(str(count))
    return wrapper


@increment
def plus_a(count):
    """
    :param str count:
    """
    print(count + "a")


plus_a(1)
```

Its output is below.

> 2a

There is no problem. Just as I intended.

But Pycharm inspection detects type error on last row.

> Expected type 'str', got 'int' instead

And furthermore, quick documentation doesn't show appropriate information with Ctrl + Q

> @increment def plus_a(count: str) -> Optional[Any]

I expect this documentation to tell like "plus_a(count: int)"

Is there any way correcting inspection and getting more appropriate documentation?

Comment: I believe it's a known issue with decorators: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19448